# 'AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'lower'' - Why doesn't the '.lower()' method doesn't work here in Python?

Tags: python, tuples, case-sensitive

I am currently learning python and doing the exercises in the module. I have learned previously how to remove any case letter in the string, so it will be easier for the user to use it later on. But it seems like when I applied the ' XXX.lower() ' method to my code, it doesnt work. It works just fine without the '.lower()' method but I really want to know why it doest work ? Here's my code :

```
# bird names list
bird_names = ("Parrot", "Owl", "Pigeon", "Crow", "Peacock", "Hen")

# bird guess
bird_guess = input("Enter a bird name (Guess 1): ")

# nested conditions starts here
if bird_guess.lower() in bird_names.lower():
  print("Yes, 1st try!")
else:
  bird_guess = input("Enter a bird name (Guess 2): ")
  if bird_guess.lower() in bird_names.lower():
    print("Yes, 2nd try!")
  else:
    bird_guess = input("Enter a bird name (Guess 3): ")
    if bird_guess.lower() in bird_names.lower():
      print("Yes, 3rd try!")
    else:
      print("Sorry, out of tries.")
```

Comment: *bird_names* is a tuple and therefore does not have built-in functionality to convert its contents to lowercase

Answer (score 5):

`bird_names` is a tuple, `.lower()` is supposed to be called on a string. You might want to consider something like

```
bird_names = ("Parrot", "Owl", "Pigeon", "Crow", "Peacock", "Hen")
bird_names = [name.lower() for name in bird_names]
```

and then you can use

```
if bird_guess.lower() in bird_names:
    ....
```

Comment: not as pythonic but can also use `bird_names = map(str.lower, bird_names)` and for checking with `in` there would be no need to convert that `map` to a list or anything (or use a generator which in terms of memory is better than the `list`; or for faster checking with `in` use a `set`)

Answer (score 2):

Because bird names is a tuple object not a string. In order for this to work what you can do is updating or overwriting the existing tuple with a list comprehension or generating a new variable. Instead of `bird_names.lower()` you can use the new list or tuple in the conditions.

```
bird_names_lower = [bird.lower() for bird in bird_names]
```

Answer (score 0):

- `bird_names` is a list object
- `.lower()` is a string function

maybe something like this can help you:

```
if bird_guess.lower() in [word.lower() for word in bird_names]:
```